# uploading base64 encoded image to twiiter

Tags: node.js, twitter

I am using [`Twitter`](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter) module for nodejs to upload media to my twitter account. As example program from here https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/tree/master/examples#media.

Instead of using image from system i am passing a base64 encoded string of the image. When i run this program it output the base64 string`(image)` in the console in a loop and after a while it crashes and doesn't upload my image.

```
// Load your image
var data = require('fs').readFileSync(image);

// Make post request on media endpoint. Pass file data as media parameter
client.post('media/upload', {media: image}, function(error, media, response){

  if (!error) {

    // If successful, a media object will be returned.
    console.log(media);

    // Lets tweet it
    var status = {
      status: 'I am a tweet',
      media_ids: media.media_id_string // Pass the media id string
    }

    client.post('statuses/update', status, function(error, tweet, response){
      if (!error) {
        console.log(tweet);
      }
    });

  }
  else{
    console.log("error upload");
  }
});
```

So i tried different method. I saved the base64 encode image in to `out.png`

```
fs.writeFile("out.png", data.image, 'base64', function (err) {
                console.log(err);                
            });

var data = require('fs').readFileSync("out.png");
```

and this code output error saying

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Local server\nodejs\out.png'

This file does exist i have confirmed

**Update**

Api returns `[Error: Status Code: 400]`

Comment: What is `data.image` in your function? It should be a path to the uploading image.

Comment: its the base64 encoded string

Comment: and what's not working?

Comment: It prints the base64 string in the console in a loop and it crashes

Comment: Updated questions with more details

Comment: And are you sure you are using the same path on upload?

Comment: @simoEndre it was variable scope issue but still its not uploading the image. Question updated.

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue?

Comment: I got the same issue. do you have a solution?

Comment: @LakshanS I did resolved my issue. But this project is way too old. I don't exactly remember how.

Comment: Got it.I fixed mine too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

hi there are several nodejs  api  which allows to serve as a client library for Twitter, and with which you can upload your media to your twitter account, the most popular [twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) and [are node-twitter-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-twitter-api)

Comment: @AkashKumar  can you give more details, your issue is it client side or server side

Comment: Updated questions with more details